# programatically set connections / variables in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Is there a way to set connections / variables programtically in airflow? I am aware this is defeating the very purpose of not exposing these details in the code, but to debug it would really help me big time if I could do something like the following pseudo code:

```
# pseudo code
from airflow import connections
connections.add({name:'...',
                 user:'...'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection is DB entity and you can create it. See below

```
from airflow import settings
from airflow.models import Connection
conn = Connection(
        conn_id=conn_id,
        conn_type=conn_type,
        host=host,
        login=login,
        password=password,
        port=port
) 
session = settings.Session() 
session.add(conn)
session.commit()
```

As for variables - just use  the API. See example below

```
from airflow.models import Variable
Variable.set("my_key", "my_value")
```

A good blog post on this topic can be found [here](https://marclamberti.com/blog/variables-with-apache-airflow/#How_to_set_a_variable_in_Airflow).

Comment: great, is there a similar thing for variables?

Comment: for variables its even much more simple. Just use `Variable.set(key,value) `

Comment: marvelous! would you add that to your original answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Do you know how to encrypt the variable value when storing them?

Comment: let's say we have a list of connections and variables that are used in all the dags, so wanted to load/store them before the dags are triggered so that in the dag code i can easily fetch them from DB. So the above code, can we run the above code during the initialization? if not where ?